# Set bottom gravity to a single view Android

Tags: android, xml

I have a horizontal linear layout, with 3 buttons, on the display. I want this layout to be displayed in the bottom of the display.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="flowepower.tetris.Game"
    android:background="@drawable/Main_screen">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
       </LinearLayout> </RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't put the buttons code, they are simple ones.

With this code, it is still displayed on the top. Can you suggest me other posibilities? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `RelativeLayout` write `android:alignParentBottom="true"` in your `LinearLayout` tag.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this is what you want...

Comment: You can add rest of your code in RelativeLayout tag.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code works for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```